# how should I understand tmp folder in app bundle? will it be cleared at some moment?

Tags: iphone, xcode, bundle, video-capture, temp

I'm capturing video using my app. I was thinking about saving the captured movie to Documents folder. I've explored project bundle and saw the captured movie is saved 2times. It's in tmp and also in my Documents folder. 
Will tmp folder be cleared or something? Or it's ok to keep the captured movie only in tmp? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files might be deleted at some point *when your app is not running*.

The `/tmp/` directory is meant for files that you don't need to persist between launches of your app. The correct directory to use depends on the requirements of your app.

There's a good description of this in Apple's [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) under *iOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside* and *Where You Should Put Your App’s Files*.